# Auto-trigger Step Functions after Terraform apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-step-functions

I have a bunch of lambda functions and one step function that orchestrate few things. All of them are created thru the same TF codebase / workspace.

Is there a way to auto-trigger the step function (create by this TF workspace) every time there was a TF apply (the step function takes zero inputs - so just triggering it would suffice).

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a hack to auto-trigger using dynamodb with lambda trigger to execute a step function on each terraform apply.

I encapsulated the whole functionality using Terraform Module :

**TFE Registry Module** : https://registry.terraform.io/modules/naveen-vijay/stepfunction-trigger-on-apply/aws/latest

**GitRepo** : https://github.com/naveen-vijay/terraform-aws-stepfunction-trigger-on-apply

[image]